# What is the best way to design the schema for the following simple example?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I have been playing about with different schemas (haven't touched databases in many years) for the following data but none seem ideal.

```
    A           B           C           D           E
1   Included    Included    Paid        Disabled    Paid
2   Included    Included    Paid        Disabled    Paid
3   N/A         N/A         N/A         Disabled    Paid
4   Included    Included    N/A         Disabled    Paid
5   N/A         N/A         Included    Disabled    Paid
```

There are currently, but likely to expand, 5 software add on A-E and again currently 5 devices 1-5 but more to come.
The software options are either included, not applicable, paid or disabled (untested).

I originally had the logic determining which device had what option in related software but there are now multiple sinks that will rely on this information so I would like to store it in the database and allow the other software to just pull the info for a given device type (1-5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a many-to-many relation between (Software)Add-On and Devices. The many-to-many relationship itself has an attribute option_value which will be an enumerated set of 4 values (included, not applicable, paid or disabled (untested)). 
*You can also make this enum as a separated Option_Value table but it will be an overkill.*

Since, it is a many-to-many relationship we will need a tertiary table which will have 2 Foreign Keys(FKs) (A Composite Foreign key) - one FK is to DEVICE and second FK is to ADDON. This tertiary table will also have a third column OPTION_VALUE which is our relationship attribute containing the 4 values as its value set. I have drawn a small diagram below to illustrate this design -

[image]

Comment: Thanks, nice and simple. I wasn't aware of composite keys but they do the job nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this

```
device
--------
+id
 title
 ...

sw_addon
--------
+id          // (PK, CK)
+device_id   // (PK, CK, FK from device table)
+addon_name  // (PK, CK)
 addon_option
 ...
```

And data this way

```
device:
-----------------
| id | title    |
-----------------
|  1 | device 1 |
|  2 | device 2 |
|  3 | device 3 |
|  4 | device 4 |
|  5 | device 5 |
-----------------

sw_addon:
----------------------------------------------
| id | device_id | addon_name | addon_option |
----------------------------------------------
|  1 |         1 | A          | Included     |
|  2 |         1 | B          | Included     |
|  3 |         1 | C          | Paid         |
|  4 |         1 | D          | Disabled     |
|  5 |         1 | E          | Paid         |
|  6 |         2 | A          | Included     |
|  7 |         2 | B          | Included     |
|  8 |         2 | C          | Paid         |
|  9 |         2 | D          | Disabled     |
| 10 |         2 | E          | Paid         |
| 11 |         3 | A          | N/A          |
| 12 |         3 | B          | N/A          |
| 13 |         3 | C          | N/A          |
| 14 |         3 | D          | Disabled     |
| 15 |         3 | E          | Paid         |
| 16 |         4 | A          | Included     |
| 17 |         4 | B          | Included     |
| 18 |         4 | C          | N/A          |
| 19 |         4 | D          | Disabled     |
| 20 |         4 | E          | Paid         |
| 21 |         5 | A          | N/A          |
| 22 |         5 | B          | N/A          |
| 23 |         5 | C          | Included     |
| 24 |         5 | D          | Disabled     |
| 25 |         5 | E          | Paid         |
----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: At least add a unique constraint on (device_id, addon_name) if you have to use a surrogate id instead of a composite primary key.